# I want to query 3 Random Products from the Database everytime only 3

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
y = (Product.objects.all()).count()
    x = random.randint(3,y)
    prouct1 = Product.objects.get(id = x+1)
    prouct2 = Product.objects.get(id = x-1)
    prouct3 = Product.objects.get(id = x-2)
```

I want to obtain 3 random products everytime i run a function initially i use the above method But the problem with this is If i delete a object Then i get the error i dont want that thing to happen obviously i can run more checks but i feel there is some simple way to do that The objective is to Get the random object from the  database every time the page is renderd

Comment: How is *this* code affected by deleting an object?

Comment: suppose i have an object whose id=5, i get the value of 5 as random int now 5 does not exist

Comment: "now 5 does not exist" -- how does choosing 5 randomly cause it not to exist?

Comment: Product.objects.get(id = x+1) I am getting some ids where x+1 product does not exist

Comment: Why would you have *any* reason to expect it to exist?

Comment: Hey @sarangkkl try this : `Product.objects.all().order_by('?')[:3]`

Comment: This is what i wanted please write answer i will accept it

Comment: @ScottHunter yes i dont have any issue it just broke the code and not work because  of the primary key missing objects cant get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can fetch random product by using [.order_by('?')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
ran_prod = Product.objects.all().order_by('?')[:3]
```

**Note :**

> order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on
> the database backend you’re using.

Comment: As is noted in the documentation: an `.order_by('?')` does not scale well, and often is slow and is not very memory conservative: what for most databases basically happens is that you create a temporary table where for each record, you "annotate" it with a random number and then you order by that random number which thus lets this run in *O(n)*. As the table grows larger, this can have serious impact on performance. I think you should copy the note in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Work with `OFFSET … LIMIT …` instead:

```
qs = Product.objects.all()
n = qs.count()
x0, x1, x2 = random.sample(range(n), 3)
product0 = qs[x0]
product1 = qs[x1]
product2 = qs[x2]
```

this requires that there are at least three items in the `Product` table, and will make *four* queries: one for the count and three for the individual products. It will also guarantee that the three products are distinct.

If the table is not that large, you can sample from the list of primary keys and then fetch three items:

```
pks = Product.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
product0, product1, product2 = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=random.sample(pks, 3))
```

This will make two queries: one to load all primary keys, and another to fetch the three products in bulk. This is more extensible if the number of products you want to fetch increases since fetching ten products for example, will still require two queries.